Do the Vedas mention Navagrahas (except Surya, Chandra and Brihaspati)?
Most of us know that Navagrahas are mentioned in Puranas. At same time, i heard and learn sometimes that the Navagrahas are mentioned in Vedas.
However, AFAIK, Surya, Chandra and Brihaspati are notable among the Navagrahas mentioned in Vedas. But, Do the others mentioned in Vedas?

Navagraha Suktam are Vedic hymns -- https://stotranidhi.com/en/navagraha-suktam-in-english/

@Rickross Can you pls provide which veda mention that Navagraha Suktam?

Yes I will search for that from one of my books .. I think the locations are mentioned in it

Isn't Soma/Chandra mentioned too?

Rahu is mentioned in Rig Veda

यत्त्वा॑ सूर्य॒ स्व॑र्भानु॒स्तम॒सावि॑ध्यदासु॒रः ।
अक्षे॑त्रवि॒द्यथा॑ मु॒ग्धो भुव॑नान्यदीधयुः ॥
O Sūrya, when the Asura's descendant Svarbhanu, pierced thee through
and through with darkness, All creatures looked like one who is
bewildered, who knoweth not the place where he is standing.
From Rig Veda 5.40.5

Sayana comments:

Svarbhānu: is a name of rāhu, the person nified ascending node, the
causer of an eclipse


an astounding find.  Samudarmanthanam is pre-figured in rig Veda @CracklingCyclone


@Rickross Can you pls provide which veda mention that Navagraha
Suktam?

Navagraha Suktam are mantras from various parts of Vedas dedicated to the nine planetary deities. These mantras are not found in one place but gathered from various portions of Vedas.
1. Aditya (Sun):
For Aditya 3 mantras are there and are as follows:

I.Adithya Sun God
(Adithya is the Sun God and is the son of Sage Kashyapa and Adhithi.
He is strong, splendid, bold, regal, warlike , victorious and
energetic*. He travels in a chariot drawn by seven horses and his
charioteer is Aruna)

The characteristics of all planets are mentioned By sage Aurabindo and are reproduced.)

Om Aa krishnena rajasa varthamano nivesayannamrutham marthya cha,
Hiranyayena savitha rathena aa devo yati, Bhuvanani pasyan. 1
Moving through darkness, Recognizing the mortal and immortal, The God
Savitha (Sun) comes in a golden chariot, And sees the world.
Agnim dhootham vrunemahe, Hotaram viswa vedasam, Asya yagnasya
sukrutham. 2
We choose the fire as the messenger, Because he has the knowledge of
entire world, And also because he does perform yajna properly.
Yesham eesepasupathi pasoonaam, Chathushpatham utha cha dvi padam,
Nishkeerthoyam yagniyam bhagamethu, Rayasposha yajna manasya santhu. 3
Thus the lord of all beings sees, The four legged and two legged
beings, Let him accept the refined sacrificial share, And let the
glorious wealth reach the performer of Yajna.
Om adhidevatha prathyadhidevatha sahithaya Adithyaya nama.
Om my salutations to sun God with all his peripheral gods.

Among these mantras the first one (marked as 1) is Rig Veda 1.35.2 the mantra marked 2 is Rig Veda 1.12.1 and the third one is Taittiriya Samhita (Krishna Yajurveda) 3.1.4. Source for my claim is the following screenshot from the book "Veda Mantras and Suktas widely used in Worship by R.L.Kashyap)

2.Angaraka

II.Angaraka Mars
(This is the planet Mars also called as Kuja and Mangala. I could not
trace his lineage. He is a politician , soldier, crafty , unscrupulous
and tyrannical)
Om Agni moordha divah kakut, Pathi prithya, Ayam aapam rethamsi
jinwathi. 1
Om Fire is in the peak of heaven, And is the consort (lord) of the
earth, And it sets in motion the essence of waters
Syona prithvi bhava . Anrukshara nivesini, Yacha na sharma sapradha. 2
Oh earth be happy, Give us thorn less abode, Which is wide and grants
us refuge.
Kshethrasya pathina vayam hitheneva, Jayamasi gam ashvam poshayitnva,
Saa no mrulathee drushe. 3
Through the master of the body who is friendly, Be victorious ,in
getting that which nourishes our energy, And let he appear to us
gracious.
Om adhidevatha prathyadhidevatha sahithaya Angarakaya nama.
Om my salutations to Mars God with all his peripheral gods.

So,for Mars too there are three mantras and their locations are Rig Veda 8.44.16, Rig Veda 1.22.15 and Rig Veda 4.57.1 respectively.
3.Shukra

III.Shukra (Venus)
(Shukra is the planet Venus and is the son of sage Brugu . His
mother’s name is Kavyaa. He was adopted as their Guru by the Asuras
and he guided them in their wars with devas. He is self willed ,
lustful, , master of state craft, poet, thinker and philosopher)
Om Pra va shukraya bhanave bharadhwam, Havyam matim cha agnaya
suputam, Yo daivani manisha janumshi, Anthar vishwani vidmana jigathi.
1
Bring the fire from the light of the sun, Oh Shukra, Offer the brain
as sacred offering in that purified fire, Which travels with the
knowledge of man, Between the births in earth and heavens.
Indranim aasu naarishhu subhagam, Aham sravam, Na hi asya aparam chana
jarasaa marate pati, Viwasmad indra uttarah. 2
The wife of Indra is most blessed among women, So I have heard, For
her consort will never die in any battle, And he is the one who is
supreme in this universe.
Indram viswahtahs pari, Havamahe janebhya, Asmkam asthu kevalaa. 3
Indra is above the entire universe, And all people give him oblations,
And let him be our only object of worship.
Om adhidevatha prathyadhidevatha sahithaya Shukraya nama.
Om my salutations to Shukra God with all his peripheral gods.

The locations for these three mantras for Shukra are Rig Veda 7.4.1, Rig Veda 10.86.11 and Rig Veda 1.7.10.
4. Soma or Chandra

IV.Soma (Moon)
(He is the moon God and rose from the ocean of milk when it was
churned. He is inconsistent, amorous, charming , imaginative and
poetical.)
Om Gaurir mimaya salilani thakshathi, Ekapadhi , dvipadhi sa
chathushpadi, Ashtapadi navapadi baboovushi, SAhasrakshara parame
vyoman. 1
Forming water of consciousness , the cow of speech is crafted, In to
one footed, two footed four footed , And she who has become eight
footed becomes nine footed, And the one with thousand letters is
supreme.
Aapyasva, Samethu they viswatha soma vrushnyam, Bhavaa vaajasya
samgadhe, 2
Oh moon, grow with us, Let your sparkling fire become united, And be
with us in our oblation.
Apsu may somo abraveedh, Anthar viswani bheshaja, Anim cha vishwa
shambhuvam, Aapascha viswabheshaji. 3
Moon has told me, All medicines are in water, And the fire bestows
happiness of all, And waters are the panacea.
Om adhidevatha prathyadhidevatha sahithaya Somaaya nama.
Om my salutations to moon God with all his peripheral gods.

Locations of these three mantras are respectively Rig Veda 1.16.41, Rig Veda 1.91.16 and Rig Veda 1.23.20.
5. Budha

V. Budha (Mercury)
(He is the planet Mercury. He is the illicit child of Moon and his
teacher Brahaspathi’s wife. He is speculative scientific , skilful.)
Om Udhbhayasva agne prathi jagrahi, Tvam ishta poorthe smsru medha
mayam cha, Puna krunvana pitara yuvana, Anvaatham sithvayi thanthu
metham. 1
Oh fire , be alert and conscious of us, May you and the Lord of the
yajna create the offering, Make my father feel young again, May he
carry out the sacrifice supported by you.
Idam vishnur vichakrame, Tredha ni thadhe padam, SAmulham asya
paamsure. 2
Thus Vishnu strode, And placed his feet thrice, And all were
established in the dust of his feet,
Vishno raratmasi, vishno prashtamasi, Vishno shjnapathra stho, Vishno
syoorasi , vishnor dhruvamasi, Vaishnavam asi vishnava tva. 3
Yajna is the forehead of Vishnu. It is the back of Vishnu, Yajna is
the purifier acting for Vishnu, Yajna is the thread of Vishnu , Yajna
is the immortal Vishnu, The principle of Vishnu exists and I want to
be one with it.
Om adhidevatha prathyadhidevatha sahithaya Budhaya nama.
Om my salutations to Budha God with all his peripheral gods.

Taittiriya Samhita 4.7.13.12/ Vajasaneyi Samhita 15.53.54, Rig Veda 1.22.17/ Taittiriya Samhita 1.2.13, Vajasaneyi Samhita (Shukla Yajurveda) 5.21.
6. Brihaspati

VI, Brahaspathi (Jupiiter)
(He is the planet Jupiter and the son of sage Angeeras. There is also
a story that he is the son of Lord Brahma himself. He was adopted as
their teacher by Devas. He is religious learned, and philosopher, wise
and a statesman.)
Om Brahaspathe athi yad aaryao arhad, Dhyumat vibhadhi
kruthumajjanneshu, Yad didhayat cchavasa rithaprajath, Thad asmasu
dravinam dehi chithram. 1
Oh Brahaspati, you do not deserve a foe, You shine among holy people
full of power, You shine with the strength born out of truth, You are
the great treasure given to us, Oh son of truth.
Indra maruthwa eha pahi somam, Yadha saaryathe apibha suthasya, Thava
praneethi thava soora sharman, AAVivasvanthi kavaya suyajna. 2
Oh Indra, drink Soma along with Maruths, As you are drinking it along
with Sharayata, Be pleased , oh heroic Brahmin, The sages expert in
Yagna are eager to serve you.
Brahma jajnaanaan pradhamam purasthaath, Viseematha surucho vena aava,
Sabudhniya upama asya vishtaa, Sathascha yonim asathascha viva. 3
The Sun was born first as an effect of the word, His brilliance
spreads over the entire world, He has revealed every thing in various
forms, He has revealed the birth place of the visible and invisible.
Om adhidevatha prathyadhidevatha sahithaya Brihaspathyaya nama.

Rig Veda 2.23.15, Rig Veda 3.51.7/ Taittiriya Samhita 1.4.18/ Vajasaneyi Samhita 7.35, Taittiriya Samhita 4.2.8/ Atharva Veda 4.1.1/ Atharva Veda 5.6.1.
7. Shanaishchara

VII. Shaischara (Saturn)
(He is the planet Saturn and the son of Sun God. He is lame and moves
slowly. He is cruel, vindictive , gloomy, immoral ,and destructive.)
Om Sham no devir abheeshtaya , aapo bhavanthu peethaye, Sham yorabhi
sravanthu na. 1
May the Goddess fulfill our wishes like water, May our wishes be
satisfied by drinking it, May the waters flow blissfully towards our
happiness.
Prajapathe na tvadethani aanyo, Viswaa jaathani pari thaa bhabhoova,
Yath kamasthe juhumasthanno asthu, Vayam syama pathayo rayeenam. 2
Oh creator , there is none like you, You pervade all that has come in
to being, Let our desires rise to you as prayers, May we become the
lord of riches.
Imam yama prastharama hi seedha, Anghirobhi pithrubhi samvidhana, Aa
thva mantra kavishastha vahanthu, Yena rajan havisha madhayasva. 3
Oh Yama come and be seated on this altar, Along with sage Angiras and
the manes, Let the mantras chanted by sages carry and bring thee, And
let this offering make you happy, Oh king.
Om adhidevatha prathyadhidevatha sahithaya Sanaischaraaya nama.
Om my salutations to Saturn God with all his peripheral gods.

Rig Veda 10.9.4, Rig Veda 10.121.10 and Rig Veda 10.14.4.
8. Rahu

VIII. Rahu (He is the son of sage Kasyapa and his Asura wife Simhika.
When Vishnu as mohini and was distributing nectar to devas, he tried
to get it by deceit. Lord Vishnu cut him in to two. Rahu is the head
portion and Kethu the body part. He is violent , head strong , frank
and furious.)
Om Kayaa naschithraa bhoovadhoothi, SAda vrudha sakha, Kayaa
sachishtaya vruthaa. 1
How will Indra come to us , picturesque one, Oh friend who is ever
waxing, And in company of the mighty ones.
AAyaam gow prashneer akramidha, Asadan mataram pura, Pitaram cha
prayantsva. 2
The variegated cow of knowledge has come, And sat before mother in the
east, And is advancing towards father’s heaven.
Yath they devi nirrytheera babanda dhama girvasu, Avicharthyam, Idham
they thad vishyam ayusho na madhyaath, Adhaa jeeva pithumadhi
pramuktha. 3
The bondage of Goddess niruthi is on your neck, And should not be
unchained, But I will loosen it from the middle part of life, And when
it is loosened, you can eat Soma*.
*The elixir of the Gods .
Om adhidevatha prathyadhidevatha sahithaya Rahuve nama.
Om my salutations to Rahu God with all his peripheral gods.

Rig Veda 4.31.1, Rig Veda 10.189.1 and Vajasaneyi Samhita 12.65/ Taittiriya Samhita 4.2.5.
9. Ketu

IX.Kethu
(He is the son of sage Kasyapa and his Asura wife Simhika. When Vishnu
as Mohini was distributing nectar to devas, he tried to get it by
deceit. Lord Vishnu cut him in to two. Rahu is the head portion and
Kethu the body part. He is secretive . meditative and unsocial.)
Om Kethum krunvanna kethave, Pesho aarys aapesase, Sam ushad bhir
jayadhaa. 1
Oh strong one you create strength in the weak, You give form to the
one who has no form, And you are born in the dawn of knowledge.
Brahma devaanaam padavi kaveenaam, Rishir vipraanaam mahisho
mrugaanaam, Syeno grudhraanaa swadhithir, Vanaanamm soma pavithra
mathyerthi rebhan. 2
Brahma of the Gods is the leader among sages, Sages among the wise are
the bull among animals, Hawk among vultures and self-law among
delights So sings Soma* among those who purify.

moon Sa chithra chithram chithayanthamasme, Chithra kshathra chithrathamam vayodhaam, Chandram rayim puruveeram bruhantham ,
Chandra chandra abhirgunathe yuvasva. 3

Oh fire you are brilliant and join us with the brilliant treasures,
And find the growth through luminous nights, Oh Chandra join him with
very delightful words, And have vast delightful wealth and keepers of
heroes.
Om adhidevatha prathyadhidevatha sahithaya Kethubhyo nama.
Om my salutations to Kethu God with all his peripheral gods.
OM adithyadhi nava graham devathabhyo nama.
Om my salutations to the nine planet Gods lead by the Sun God.
Om Shanthi, Om Shanthi, Om Shanthi Let there be peace, let there be
peace and let there be peace.

Rig Veda 1.6.3, Rig Veda 9.96.6, Rig Veda 6.6.7.
Source of all the info given here is the book mentioned above.
